# Using Bitmap Class in XAML

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, binding, bitmap

I've defined access to my resources for my WPF project in XAML as follows:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
```

Now I want to make use of this in my XAML view following [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970269%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) guidelines, i.e.,

```
<Image Height="100">
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage DecodePixelHeight="60" UriSource="{x:Static properties:Resources.MyImage"/>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

However, binding to resources returns a Bitmap and not the required Uri type. How do I correctly reference my Bitmap in XAML as the source for an image?

N.B. I want to avoid hard-coded path strings in XAML, hence the reference to properties.

Comment: Can you clarify: Is Resources.MyImage pointing to a bitmap, or a string/path/uri?

Comment: An Image was added to the resources of the project, and that is what I'm pointing to, i.e., a bitmap.

Comment: Have you tried binding the Image directly to the resource? (i.e. `<Image Source="{x:Static properties:Resources.MyImage}"/>` )

Comment: You say MyImage is a Bitmap not a URI ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15008178/1136211) may also be helpful.

Comment: @olitee - Yes, this doesn't work as it's the wrong type.

Comment: @Clemens - Thought this may be the case. Was interested to know if it was possible from resources without some kind of converter.