# WPF Tile Brush throws exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, resources

I am trying to use the tile brush to add a nice wood texture to my project. I have included a resource file, added the resource and selected the image from the ImageSource drop down. The image appears in the preview but throws an exception when I run the program.

This is the XAML code that has been added for the fill.

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
     <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/WoodTexture.bmp" TileMode="Tile"/>
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

The exception that is thrown is this

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '24' and line position '22'.
```

Does this have something to do with the way the resource has been loaded in, or am I referencing it wrong?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25714375/1136211), and make sure that you either use a Resource File Pack Uri like `pack://application:,,,/Resources/WoodTexture.bmp` or in XAML just `/Resources/WoodTexture.bmp`.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Does this mean I don't need the resources file?

Comment: That's right, you don't need a resource file. See also the last section in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15008178/1136211).