# Setting a transparent image from user resource file as image source in WPF code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, code-behind

Different versions of this question are already asked, yet solutions to those questions don't feet my requirements.

Assume We have a resource file named `MyResource.resx` and an image file `Accept.png` in a project folder called `Icons` and a refrence to this image is in `MyResource.resx`.

**I'm looking for a way to set source of an Image UIElement with following requirements:**

1. **Refactor name of image and** ...
2. **Keep it's transparency**
3. **And become aware when I accidentally remove the image file from it's location (compile errors should happen).**

Here are what I already tested.

1:In Code behind:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Icons\Accept.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

The problem with this code is: No refactoring is possible, and even worst, errors related to wrong uri are only in run-time.

2: Again in code behind:

```
myImage.Source = MyResource.Accept.ToBitmapImage()
```

where `.ToBitmapImage()` is a method I've found in internet:

```
public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
                return bitmapImage;
            }
        }
```

The Only problem with this code is that image Transparency is Lost.

In Xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="/Icons/Accept.png" />
```

The problem with this code is: No refactoring is possible, and errors related to wrong uri are not shown. they are not even noticed in runtime.

I tried to use the resource file right in the xaml, following [this tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22420.binding-to-resources-resx-files-in-xaml.aspx) but i've failed.

So how to do this.

Comment: Transparency is obviously lost due to the image format you're using for encoding and decoding. Replacing `ImageFormat.Bmp` by `ImageFormat.Png` should solve that problem. Or use one of the other conversion methods mentioned in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/94456/1136211). Besides that, you typically don't use `.resx` files in WPF applications anyway.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the comment.  Replacing ImageFormat.Bmp by ImageFormat.Png worked fine. But I was also hoping for a way to do this in XAML so I could see the resulting UI. And why you typically don't use .resx files in WPF applications? I'm new to WPF anyway.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15008178/1136211) may be helpful.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks again for another helpful comment. And I've decided to use uri and instead of a simple string, I would use: var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/" + nameof(MyResource.Red)); So I can refactor whenever I want to.