# Image not displayed at runtime (only in design)

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I have a WPF application, in which I want to insert an image. It shows up just fine in the design, but once I run the program nothing is displayed. The image is imported and stored using *Project > Properties > Resources.resx* and is located in the folder "Resources" as you can see in the screenshot in the bottom. The XAML code is quite simple:

```
<Image 
    Source="/Resources/warning_icon_32x32.png" 
    Width="32" 
    Height="32" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Why does this not work? As you can see below, it works fine in the designer.

[image: Image shown in the designer]

[image: Image location in project]

**EDIT**

If I use the full path of the image (i.e. `C:\...`) then it works. However this would break as soon as it was opened on a different PC, so it's hardly a solid solution. It it interesting though...

Comment: Make sure the image file is part of your Visual Studio project, located in a folder named Resources. Also set its Build Action to Resource.

Comment: It was the build action which was the issue (see also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690774/assign-bitmapimage-from-resources-resx-to-image-source/12693661#12693661)

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008178/1136211