# Resource png loses quality after convert bitmap to ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a PNG with transparency that loses a lot of quality when I convert it to ImageSource. What I do to convert it is the following:

```
public static ImageSource ToImageSource()
    {   Bitmap bitmap = Properties.Resources.Image;
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        ImageSource wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(wpfBitmap, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);

        return wpfBitmap;
    }
```

But the quality is really bad. when I call directly to the file on my computer the quality is correct:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="14" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\Image.png" Width="14" Height="14"></Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Is there another way to transform the resource without losing quality and transparency?

Comment: "BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality" This bit wasn't a clue?

Comment: @SteveTodd sorry, It was a test to see if something changed. I have already modified the question

Comment: Is ImageSource your fixed output type? or is it flexible?

Comment: @Gowshik I need to show the png in my WPF window (and the image is sent from another project in the solution). If there is another option I do not mind modifying the type.

Comment: Note that WPF's unit system is device independent, with the unit being equivalent to 1/96 inch. Thus, `<Image ... Width="14" Height="14" />` will display the image the scaled to a width and height of 14/96 inch (assuming your display device correctly reports its DPI settings). You can disable this scaling behavior by setting the Image control property `Stretch` accordingly. Also note that the Image control might not necessarily align the bitmap pixels with the display pixel grid, possibly causing some blur. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) To enforce pixel-aligned rendering for your bitmap, set the `SnapsToDevicePixels` property of the Image control to `true`. If none of my suggestions here helps, please edit your question and add links to both your original PNG and a (lossless, preferably no JPG) screenshot of how the image is being rendered in your UI.

Comment: @elgonzo with `<Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImage, Mode=OneWay}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="None" ></Image>` keeps happening

Comment: Throw away the entire conversion code. Instead, load the image directly from an assembly resource file, as e.g. shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714375/1136211 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008178/1136211

Answer (score 0):

Sadly i can not test your code but i think you have to set the Mode to NearestNeighbor

Try this

```
public static ImageSource ToImageSource()
{   
   Bitmap bitmap = Properties.Resources.Image;
   IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

   ImageSource wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
       hBitmap,
       IntPtr.Zero,
       Int32Rect.Empty,
       BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
   RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(wpfBitmap, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);

   return wpfBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Same result, the "SetBitmapScalingMode" seems don't change anything

Comment: @Aragorn try to do both: NearestNeighbor and HighQuality

Comment: Nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Or... try this :)

```
public static ImageSource ToImageSource()
{
     Bitmap bitmap = Properties.Resources.Image;
     IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

     ImageSource wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                        hBitmap,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        new Int32Rect(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

      DeleteObject(hBitmap);
      return wpfBitmap;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

Calling `DeleteObject` will release the GDI handle.

Comment: I had also tried that but the image still goes wrong.

Comment: Strange ... I'm using this code now without any problem. Are you sure that the image from "Properties.Resources.Image" is OK?

Comment: Yes, maybe it's because the image is inside a datagrid and the column width is 15 and the row height 20

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your image path here", UriKind.Relative));
```

Edit: Assuming you have the image path.